# How do I fix an internal error Xcode 9b2?

Tags: xcode9-beta, xcode9

Tried compiling my project after installing Xcode 9 b2 and I keep on getting this error:

```
/Users/Cyril/Desktop/App/App/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/39/mgnz9fv159l_w86z0y_dh8lh0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2017-06-21_21-56-59_829000".
```

I've tried cleaning the project, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode and rebooting but to no avail. 
Any help?

Comment: I'd file the bug with apple and then completely uninstall Xcode beta and re-install it.

Comment: Wait for a patch. There's really nothing you can do unless you can find out what feature you're using that causes it to break.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu building the project in Xcode 8 then running in Xcode 9 seems to have solved the issue

Comment: @cyril I’ve experienced stuff like that before, glad you got it sorted. You could probably post that as an answer for the next person with this issue.